# C# Unlocking directory and copying files

Tags: c#

I have to delete directory with application exe file.
It's looks like this:

> 1. Start App.exe from C:\Folder\App.exe
> 2. App.exe copying itself to C:\User\Temp\Temp.exe
> 3. App.exe is closing itself and run Temp.exe
> 4. Temp.exe is deleting App.exe and C:\Folder directory

It's look nice but when I'm copying App.exe to Temp.exe, process Temp.exe is still using C:\Folder.
No matter what I do every process which I started is locking my directory.

I've made a form app with button click to check their behavior.

```
    bool del = false;
    public Form1(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString();
        if (args.Length > 0 && args[0] == "arg1")
        {
            Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(args[1]));
            proc.Kill();
        }
        else if (args.Length > 0 && args[0] == "arg2")
        {
            del = true;
        }
        else
        {
            string tempfile = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + "\\Temp.exe";
            File.Copy(Application.ExecutablePath, tempfile, true);
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = tempfile;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("arg1 {0}", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
            proc.Start();
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (del == true)
        {
            string ApplicationPath = @"C:\Folder";
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(ApplicationPath);
            foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles()) file.Delete();
            Directory.Delete(ApplicationPath);
        }
        else
        {
            ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            Info.Arguments = "/C ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 && \"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\" arg2";
            Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            Info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            Info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            Process.Start(Info);
        }
    }
```

In the short way - I'm looking for solution that will remove starting exe file with parent directory.

Hope for help. Thanks.

Comment: Mostly a guess, but perhaps you need to change the current working directory first?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory

Comment: On your button click event handler, if del == true... inside that if statement do a check that the files in the folder are not in use

Comment: @David thanks! I've change working directory and now it's fine.

Comment: @user5817386: Excellent!  I'll put together an answer for it below so future users might more easily find this.  One moment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that the application is still *running* from the current directory, even if it's running a separate executable.  Consider, for example, a command line:

```
C:\SomeFolder>../AnotherFolder/SomeProgram.exe
```

While `SomeProgram` may be in `AnotherFolder`, I *myself* am "in" `SomeFolder` and, thus, keeping open a reference to it.  So it can't be deleted.

You should be able to [change the current working directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory) from code, though.  Something like this:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"C:\User\Temp");
```